# Can I blindly replace all occurrences of document.all in my entire project with document.getElementsByTagName('*')?

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname

I'm working on a lot of legacy code and have a huge number of instances of **document.all** usage. I need to replace all these instances (in bulk) with something Microsoft supports (as I understand document.all *is not supported anymore*).

Is it a safe option to replace all the instances of document.all with **document.getElementsByTagName(*)***? Please bear in mind that document.all could come in many flavours like document.all.item("") etc.. I need to know if document.getElementsByTag('') would work as a solution for blind replacement of document.all wherever it is used (in whatever form)

Comment: refactoring should always be done in small steps... therefore I would advise not to blindly replace all occurrences

Comment: No, you should replace each individual pattern ("usage flavour") with the respective fix.

Comment: true, but unless your code base is backed by enough tests (which might not be the case since this is legacy code) I'd say don't venture into unknown, these are DOM APIs we're talking about :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [MDN page about *#document*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document#Properties)

> `document.all`
>   Provides access to all **elements with an id**. This is a legacy, non-standard, interface and you should use the `document.getElementById()` method instead.

Therefore, no `document.getElementsByTagName("*")` will return more elements than just *elements with an id*

This definition means you could do

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id]'); // NodeList
```

### However

[**MSDN has a different definition**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537434(v=vs.85).aspx)

> The **all** collection includes one element object for each *valid HTML tag*. If a valid tag has a matching end tag, both tags are represented by the same element object.

In this case it is true that `document.getElementsByTagName("*")` gives a similar result (*HTMLCollection*)

### However, again

The *NodeList* will fail to reproduce the expected result of `document.all.id_value`, `document.all[id_value]` or `document.all(foo)`.

The *HTMLCollection* does support `document.all.id_value` and `document.all[id_value]` as described in [**w3's DOM spec**](http://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#interface-htmlcollection), though I strongly recommend against use of this over other methods such as `getElementById`

Really, you're going to have to go through the code quickly to make sure it will work as expected with whichever alternative you choose.

Comment: Actually, replacing document.all[id_value] with document.getElementsByTagName('*')[id_value] works

Comment: @Ranjit oh you are correct, looks like _HTMLCollection_ does have these as non-enumerable properties ([**spec**](http://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#interface-htmlcollection)), but I have never seen this actually used

Answer (score 0):

> Can I blindly replace all occurrences of document.all in my entire project with document.getElementsByTagName('*')?

No. `document.all` isn't a collection of elements by tag name, it's a collection of elements of various types that are included in it for various reasons. Some of those reasons are:

- Elements with an `id` are included.
- Some elements with `name` are also included.
- The `head`, `body`, and `title` are included.

So there will have to be intelligence in the process. You'll likely replace uses of `document.all` with:

- `document.getElementById`, which returns a single element, the element with the matching `id` (if the document is invalid and has more than one matching element, browsers usually return the first of them in document order)
- `document.querySelector`, which returns the first matching element in the document for any valid CSS selector
- `document.querySelectorAll`, which returns a list of matching elements in the document for any valid CSS selector

(Those last two are present in all modern browsers, and also IE8.)

Examples:

Find the `<div id="foo">..</div>` element:

```
document.getElementById("foo")
```

Find the first element with the class `bar` in the document:

```
document.querySelector(".bar")
```

Find all `a` elements in the document:

```
document.querySelectorAll("a")
```

Refs:

- [MDN `document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document#Properties)
- [MSDN `document.all`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537434(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @t-j-crowder - So from this answer it looks like getelementsbytagname would return a superset of data as compared to document.all - that would be ok as it would already pick an id or a name which is there in the page.

Comment: @Ranjit: Not a superset, a subset. But it returns a fundamentally different data structure. `document.all` is like a dictionary; the `NodeList` returned by `getElementsByTagName` is a list.